# SQL query failed for Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have the following query, it failed when I try to run it in Hive. Can someone help me reconstruct it? Thank you!

```
select topic, partition_c, untilOffset from playground.kafka_offset
where group_c = 'consumer-group-3' 
and commitTime = ( 
    select max(commitTime) 
    from playground.kafka_offset
    where group_c = 'consumer-group-3'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select topic, partition_c, untilOffset
from (select ko.*,
             max(commitTime) over (partition by group_c) as max_commitTime
      from playground.kafka_offset ko
      where group_c = 'consumer-group-3' 
     ) ko
where commitTime = max_commitTime;
```

Comment: It doesn't recognize `ko.*` in line 2, however if I use `*` instead of `ko.*`. It worked. Do you think it is work the same way as what I required? Thank you!

Comment: @ZHENBIAN . . . This should be exactly equivalent.